# How can I use margin inside td in table but without using border-collapse: separate

Tags: html, css

Let say I want to make a table like this:
[image: you can see the color border have a separate color and margin inside the table data]

I can already make the example if using `border-collapse: separate` property but the line itself get separated like this

[image: you can see the top border]

when I'm using `border-collapse: collapse` I can make the border still there but I can't make the margin itself

```css
#home-table table {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #1d3962;
  margin: 0% auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: none;
  border-top: none;
}

#home-table .table-icon-img-size {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

#home-table tr {
  border-top: solid 3px rgba(58, 115, 197, 0.1) !important;
}

#home-table th {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #1d3962;
}

#home-table tr:nth-child(1) {
  border-top: none !important;
}

#home-table tr:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

#home-table td {
  width: 25%;
}

#home-table .first {
  border-top: solid 3px rgba(58, 115, 197, 0.2) !important;
  border-top-radius: 10px;
}

#home-table td {
  margin: 0% 300px;
}

#home-table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  padding: 32px 38px;
  text-align: center;
}

#home-table tr th:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(46, 207, 47, 0.1);
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  padding: 32px 38px;
}

#home-table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgba(46, 207, 47, 0.1);
  padding: 32px 38px;
  text-align: center;
}

#home-table tr th:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(219, 206, 44, 0.1);
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  padding: 32px 38px;
}

#home-table tr td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rgba(219, 206, 44, 0.1);
  padding: 32px 38px;
  text-align: center;
}

#home-table tr th:nth-child(4) {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(229, 76, 110, 0.1);
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  padding: 32px 38px;
}

#home-table tr td:nth-child(4) {
  text-align: center;
  color: #E54C6E;
  background-color: rgba(229, 76, 110, 0.1);
  padding: 32px 38px;
  margin: 0% 500px;
}

#home-table .test {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#home-table tr td {
  padding: 32px 38px;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-table">
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Diamond</td>
        <td>650</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>160</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Diamond</td>
        <td>650</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>160</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Diamond</td>
        <td>650</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>160</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me to solve this? I'm quite confused with this problem

**EDIT 1**

If what I want to get is not clear I hope this image can make what I want to get more clearly

[image: This is The Description To made it easier to Understand]

currently we still in the bottom image when the border-top line still separated but what I want to get that the border-top line still attached to it

Comment: Insist to use `table` tag?

Comment: General meaning of 'margin' in HTML world is the distance beteween two separate elements. You cannot specify margin to td in table. All you can use is padding between data.

Comment: @Pedram yes since it easier to make it more clean for the gap, I mean cell give a nice grid

Comment: @JustCode yup as you said, I tried using margin but nothing happen, so I try to use padding for content but still not with the background since it in the same element

Answer (score 1):

I have trying to fix your issues please check this link:[demo](https://codepen.io/lokendra-baghel/pen/yLypzbN)

Basically CSS property need to update, few properties need to update to get the resolution of the design issue

```css
#home-table table {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #1d3962;
  margin: 0% auto;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: none;
  border-top: none;
}

#home-table .table-icon-img-size {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

#home-table tr td {
  position: relative;
  /*border-top: solid 3px rgba(58, 115, 197, 0.1) !important;*/
}

#home-table tr td:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(58, 115, 197, 0.1) !important;
  height: 3px;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  top: 5px;
}

#home-table tr td:first-child:before {
  content: '';
  left: 0px;
}

#home-table tr td:last-child:before {
  content: '';
  right: 0px;
}

#home-table th {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #1d3962;
}

#home-table tr:nth-child(1) {
  border-top: none !important;
}

#home-table tr:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

#home-table td {
  width: 25%;
}

#home-table .first {
  border-top: solid 3px rgba(58, 115, 197, 0.2) !important;
  border-top-radius: 10px;
}

#home-table td {
  margin: 0% 300px;
}

#home-table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  padding: 32px 38px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
}

#home-table tr th:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(46, 207, 47, 0.1);
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  padding: 32px 38px;
}

#home-table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgba(46, 207, 47, 0.1);
  padding: 32px 38px;
  text-align: center;
}

#home-table tr th:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(219, 206, 44, 0.1);
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  padding: 32px 38px;
}

#home-table tr td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rgba(219, 206, 44, 0.1);
  padding: 32px 38px;
  text-align: center;
}

#home-table tr th:nth-child(4) {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(229, 76, 110, 0.1);
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  padding: 32px 38px;
}

#home-table tr td:nth-child(4) {
  text-align: center;
  color: #E54C6E;
  background-color: rgba(229, 76, 110, 0.1);
  padding: 32px 38px;
  margin: 0% 500px;
}

#home-table .test {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#home-table tr td {
  padding: 32px 38px;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-table">
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Diamond</td>
        <td>650</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>160</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Diamond</td>
        <td>650</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>160</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Diamond</td>
        <td>650</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>160</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a little description of your changes would help the OP to understand what was going wrong.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer but, the top border or line is still got separated from the right and left table

Comment: @Rakish Frisky, I am not getting your point, can you please more explain in the detail because as per you mentioned in the screenshot. we have solved this issue. please give me a proper wireframe for better understand.

Comment: @LokendraBaghel I'm sorry if the description not to complete, I already add my Edit in thread with the illustration I want to get

Comment: @Rakish Frisky, I have updated the CSS code. please verify at your end. if any modifications will require the let us know.